# Jmeter - Set custom text on request tab using JSR223 sampler

Tags: rest, groovy, jmeter, request-headers

I am creating a script on groovy to be able to send http requests.
 
To call this script I'm using the JSR223 Sampler 
The thing is that I would like to reproduce as much as possible the behaviour that a HTTP Sampler has, meaning that I want to perform the request and also to fill the sampler's info (Response data, Request and Response)
Although I'm able to obtain `SampleResult` and set Response data and Response, does not seem to exist a method to set our own request string:
https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html

Following the docs, the closest method to do what I want is the `setRequestHeaders()`.

If I call that method like this `SampleResult.setRequestHeaders("My custom text")` something like this appears on the request tab:

```
File C:\Users\UserName\groovy_file.groovy
Request Headers:
My custom text
```

Is there any way to print only the string `My custom text`, on the Request?

**EDIT**

Sampler must use a script file instead of the script field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be just overwriting the data using [`prev.samplerData()`](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setSamplerData-java.lang.String-) shorthand from the [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor)

```
prev.samplerData = 'put the desired request data here'
```

where `prev` stands for the parent [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) class instance, check out [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/) article for more information on the [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) shorthands available for the JSR223 Test Elements.

If you don't want the PostProcessor you can still call the same function from your Groovy script like:

```
SamplerResult.setSamplerData('put the desired request data here')
```

Comment: It was it! Thanks! I just couldn't find it, because the official docs do not actually mention what that method does